# FAST corner detector robustness

Tags: performance, opencv, sift, surf

I am studying FAST,SURF and SIFT, what I concluded is that SIFT and SURF are scale and rotation invariant due the way they extract the point. as both SURF and SIFT look in multiple scales and assign a direction to the detected point. this assigned direction in detection phase is used as a reference direction to be used in SURF and SIFT descriptor.

But FAST only detect a point without scale nor a direction assignment. so it is not invariant to both. but when used in OpenCV with SIFT or SURF descriptor it will show invariant even to 180 degrees.
My question is >> Is the point direction (which used as the reference) assigning  done in the descriptor also?

Comment: direction isn't extracted in detection phase afair. Not to mistake with detection invariance. So sift and surf detectors are invariant to rotation, but orientation is computed in the description step!. But scale is computed in detection phase.

Comment: so both orientation histograms for point detection and point descriptor are done in description phase?

Comment: not sure about sift but for surf I'm quite sure that orientation computation is done at the begonning of descriptor computation only. For SIFT isnt detection only a DoG from scale space pyramid?

Comment: yes in detection phase keypoint is selected based on DoG, and it given an orientation so that the descriptor could use it as reference,

Comment: in surf those are 3 steps: 1. extract keypoints 2. extract orientation 3. extract oriented descriptor. Number 2 and 3 can be combined to a single "description" step. Is this different for sift? MUST orientation belong to detection phase there? In fact it doesnt make much sense because orientation is only important for description and "provided keypoints" (which are allowed in opencv) don't make sense if the descriptor doesn't compute an orientation for them. So probably orientation is only computed during (beginning) description state.